# Reflecting ray on triangle in 3D space

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, geometry, raycasting

I am working in a 3D space. I have a ray, or more specifically the start and transmission vector of a ray in 3D space. I also have a triangle, which I know for a fact is hit by the ray. By triangle I of course mean I have three 3D points. I can also calculate a normal vector from this triangle easily.

Now I need to get a new ray, which would be the reflection after that specific hit.

I also don't know exacltly where on the triangle the point of contact is, but it obviously has to be taken into account to get the reflected ray. That point would be the start of that new ray.

This is trivial to do in 2D, but I can't figure out how to do it in 3D.

I am using C++ and OpenFrameworks with the ofxRay add-on.

Comment: Are you comfortable with vector algebra, like adding two vectors, or taking dot products?

Comment: A helpful way to think might be this: the normal to the plane (triangle) and ray together form a plane. In this plane you retrieve the 2D problem that you are familiar with. So, you could find this 2D space, solve the problem there, and then transform back. This will be mathematically equivalent to a vector algebra formula (as @Beta points out), which would probably be the most efficient (or at least computationally straight-forward) solution method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem splits cleanly into two problems: find the point where the ray meets the triangle -- which is the point of origin of the reflected ray -- and find the direction (vector) of the reflected ray.

Let the normal vector of the triangle be **n**. The equation describing the plane of the triangle is

**nx** = k

You can determine k by plugging one of the triangle vertices into that equation. The equation of the incident ray is

**x** = t**v** + **p**

where **p** is the point of origin of the ray, and **v** is its (normalized) direction. To find the point of intersection of the ray, just solve this pair of equations, which comes down to solving

**n**(t**v** + **p**) = k

for t, then plugging that back into the equation for the ray.

To find the direction of the reflected ray, we must reverse the component of the incident ray parallel to the triangle's normal:

**v<sub>r</sub>** = **v** + 2(**vn**)**v**

(Watch out for the sign-- I assumed that the normal points out of the face which the ray hits.)